# How to extend globalThis/global type?

Tags: typescript, global, prisma

I'm working on a typescript project with [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) and I saw this code on [this guide](https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-prisma-postgres#step-3.-install-and-generate-prisma-client) that is using typescript. However my linter gives me errors for the following code.

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

let prisma: PrismaClient;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
  if (!global.prisma) {
    global.prisma = new PrismaClient();
  }
  prisma = global.prisma;
}

export default prisma;
```

The error message for lines 8,9,11 (for `global.prisma`) is the following

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature. ts(7017)

How can I extend the type of globalThis or global with `Prismaclient` so that it works as intended?

Comment: Learn and use the singleton pattern so you don't have to hack it like this.

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh Could you give an example of how you would solve this?

Comment: Thanks for posting this question! Was facing the exact same issue a year later and it was causing me tons of headaches.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the solution suggested in [Best practice for instantiating PrismaClient with Next.js](https://www.prisma.io/docs/support/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices) in the Prisma docs.

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient | undefined
}

export const prisma =
  global.prisma ||
  new PrismaClient()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') global.prisma = prisma
```

#### Alternative Solution

You could just explicitly cast `global` to `any`. Abusing casts can defeat the value of using typescript, but *in this specific context* I don't see any harm or risk.

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
  if (!(global as any).prisma) {
    (global as any).prisma = new PrismaClient();
  }
  prisma = (global as any).prisma;
}
```

Comment: Alternative solution though hacky, is good workaround